# How can I modify files/folders on a network share as another user?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

#### Summary

As part of our build process on DevOps, I'm trying to copy over the build artifact to a specific folder on an internal network share. Problem is, although the build agent is on our internal network, the DevOps service does not have permissions to access any of the network shares.

I think I can get around this by supplying valid login credentials in the PowerShell script that does the work, but I'm having trouble getting the credentials to be accepted. Though viewing the folder structure without credentials seems to be possible, actually making modifications (create/delete files and/or folders) is giving me access denied or authentication denied messages.

#### What I've Tried

At first, I was doing a very simple create folder command:

```
# NETWORK_SHARE would be the internal IP of the target public folder on the network, like 12.345.678.90
New-Item -Path "NETWORK_SHARE\path\to\folder" -ItemType Directory
```

But that was giving me an Access Denied error:

> New-Item : Access to the path 'folder' is denied.

Then I did some research and thought that perhaps if I supply the credentials of a valid user, it would allow me to do this. Here's the simple test command. It's supposed to create a new folder in a specified location:

```
$username = "MyUsername"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "MyPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $password

# NETWORK_SHARE would be the internal IP of the target public folder on the network, like 12.345.678.90
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "NETWORK_SHARE" -ScriptBlock { New-Item -Path $args[0] -ItemType Directory } -Cred $credentials -Authentication Credssp -ArgumentList "NETWORK_SHARE\path\to\folder"
```

The error that I'm getting is the following:

> Connecting to remote server NETWORK_SHARE failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. CredSSP
> authentication is currently disabled in the client configuration. Change the client configuration and try the request again. CredSSP authentication must also be enabled in the server configuration. Also, Group Policy must be edited to allow credential delegation to the target computer. Use gpedit.msc and look at the following policy: Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Credentials Delegation -> Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials.  Verify that it is enabled and configured with an SPN appropriate for the target computer. For example, for a target computer name "myserver.domain.com", the SPN can be one of the following: WSMAN/myserver.domain.com or WSMAN/*.domain.com

It doesn't even look like it's trying to authenticate, it just immediately spits back the error above. I'm not sure how to go about debugging this. I can make changes to the build agent if necessary, but I do not have the ability to change any configuration on the target network share, as that is maintained by the IT team and they are very strict about opening up our drives to the internet. Is there a way to authenticate successfully to create a new folder on the network share without changing any configuration on the target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking a non-Powershell approach to this. Since I had access to the build agent, I configured the DevOps service to run with the credentials of a valid user instead of the default "Network Service" user. This granted the DevOps service all the permissions it needed, and I was able to write a trivial PS script that creates/copies/deletes folders on the network share.